# Is the phrase "ranging from" a noun or an adjective?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I have seen many present participles, some act as a noun, e.g. Reading is fun, and some act as an adjective, e.g. Look at the reading boy.

However, I am not sure whether it is a noun or an adjective in the sentence e.g. Here are dog breeds *ranging from* $300 to $15000.

Comment: I would say it was functioning as a verb, since you could change it to '...which range from...'.

Comment: "Reading" is a verb in "the reading boy". "Ranging"  is also a verb in the non-finite participial clause "ranging from $300 to $1500", which modifies "breeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the phrase "ranging from $300 to $15000" is functioning as an adjective, modifying the noun "dog breeds".

You are correct that the "-ing" forms of verbs (when not part of a larger verb construction) generally function as either nouns or adjectives.  When they are adjectives, they are called the "present participle".  When they function as nouns, they are actually called "gerunds" instead, thus in the sentence:

> Reading is fun.

"Reading" is actually technically a gerund (noun made from a verb), but in

> the reading boy

"reading" is a participle (adjective made from a verb).

In the case of

> dog breeds ranging from $300 to $15000

"ranging from ..." here cannot be a noun phrase, because that would make a noun ("dog breeds") followed directly by another noun, which basically doesn't ever happen in English, so this is an indicator that you must be looking at an adjective phrase instead.  Another clue is that this phrase really doesn't make any sense on its own if you separate it from "dog breeds", as its purpose in the sentence is to clarify/specify which dog breeds are being described.  Since its function is to modify a noun, that makes it an adjective.